# Can't install OpenCv on Mac: there are no files in /usr/local

Tags: macos, opencv

I've downloaded tar.gz files from official site(versions 2.4.3, 2.4.7, 2.4.8). Then unzipped them somewhere.

```
mac-mini-olia:Data olia$ cd opencv-2.4.6.1/
mac-mini-olia:opencv-2.4.6.1 olia$ mkdir build
mac-mini-olia:opencv-2.4.6.1 olia$ cd build/
mac-mini-olia:build olia$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
mac-mini-olia:build olia$ make -j8
```

after the last command output is 
3910 warnings and 12 errors generated.
Errors are like

```
/Volumes/Data/opencv-2.4.6.1/3rdparty/libjpeg/._jcapimin.c:1:4096: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
```

and

```
/Volumes/Data/opencv-2.4.6.1/3rdparty/libpng/._pngerror.c:1:2: error: expected identifier or '('
```

And after that in **/usr/local/lib** and **/usr/local/include** there are no files of opencv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to install OpenCV on OSX.
You can use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)
Make sure you have XCode installed with it's Command Line Tools first.
(An easy way to test that is to see if `xcodebuild` if a found command in Terminal)

After you install MacPorts simply do

```
sudo port install opencv
```

This will take care of building the project from source and installing it for you.
(The path might be `/opt/local/lib` `/opt/local/include` though, haven't used it in a while)

There are also port variants: opencv with options. For example if you plan to use openni 1.5.x and have it integrated with opencv you can try

```
sudo port install opencv +openni
```

If you do

```
sudo port variants opencv
```

you should get a list of all the options(e.g. python support, qt support, etc.)

If you want to build from source yourself, I recommend installing the `ccmake` command (I think macports can also do that for you) or use the [CMake](http://cmake.org/) gui tool. This will allow you to easily configure the build and setup your install location(/use/local/...and so on)

So you can try someting like this:

```
cd /path/to/your/opencv_folder
mkdir build && cd build
ccmake ..
```

At this stage you should see something like this:
[image: OpenCV CCMake]

hit Enter to change an option and Enter again to exit edit mode and use the up/down keys to scroll through the options. When you're happy with the settings, press C to configure. Once that's done, you can press G to generate. This will generate the makefiles for you so you can do this:

```
make
sudo make install
```

make install will actually copy the built libraries/headers to the /usr/ folder.
You might run into errors when running make, depending on your setup(e.g. if you're missing dependencies, etc.), but the cool thing about ccmake is that you can go back, run it again, disable the things you don't want to build right now and go back to the make stage.